# How to determine memory consumption of Sqlite in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, sqlite

We use file based Sqlite via jdbc in our Scala app. I suspect we consume to much process memory using it as our Process gets killed by the linux oom killer, but I have fixed every memory area of the JVM and also did an analysis with NMT which looks fine.

So the candidate left is the native library which can't really be tracked by the JVM tools.

Is there any way to find out how memory Sqlite is currently using in our whole process? I saw this here (answer mnentions sqlite3-status) but I am not sure if I can use that in our JDBC based approach.

Comment: There's a [C API function](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/memory_highwater.html) for finding that information, but I doubt it's been made available through the Java bindings.

Comment: You might see if your version of sqlite was compiled with support for the [memstat](https://www.sqlite.org/memstat.html) extension. (Or try to load it if not).

Comment: Cheers, I will try to compile it for our ARM busybox system. I also found this, which I try to build into our app to get a fixed limit:

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_hard_heap_limit